# Modify Javascript with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, timer, web

I have a webpage with javascript and there is a timer on it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            (function($){

                var count = 10;
                countdown = setInterval(function () {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        $("#countdown").remove();
                    }
                    count--
                }, 1000);

                $(document).on('submit', 'form.proform', function() {
                    if(count > 0)
                        return false;
                });

            })(jQuery);
            </script>
```

Now I wanted to create a C# application to have a client.
But I don't want to wait for the timer until I can watch the hole site.
Is the a way to modify the `var count` in C# to skip the timer?
Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

In Js:

```
var count = <%=CountValue%>;
```

In C#:

```
public int CountValue{ get { return this._countValue; } set { _countValue = value; } }
```

Set the value of count in page load like this

```
this._countValue=0;
```